# How can I generate comparable spec documents?

Tags: specifications

Currently in my company we're using Excel as a tool to write specs.

On the kind of projects we're working on, spec changes are a matter of course, and constitute a lot of the work, beyond the implementation.

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to write a spec, including screenshots and arrows, but with comparable content. i.e., something that will allow me to compare between versions of the spec.

Free tools are better, but I guess anything with a license of less than 100USD will be OK too.

Answer (score 1):

MS Word handles text and pictures, and has a document diff'ing tool built in.   Open Office (being a MS Word Clone) may have something similar, and is free.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [XMLmind Editor](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/) will interest you.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent free Sequence Diagram editor: [QUICK SEQUENCE DIAGRAM EDITOR](http://sdedit.sf.net). It's artifact is an xml document with CDATA tag which encloses simple DSL used for SD declaration.